# Using a single method for setting/getting values instead of two?

Tags: php, class, coding-style, getter-setter

Is it a good idea to replace getter and/or setter methods with a single method handling both?

For example:

```
    function name($what = null){

      if(!$what)
        return $this->name;

      $this->name = $what;
    }
```

Used like:

```
    // get name
    print $obj->name();

    // set name
    $obj->name('bla');
```

I've seen some frameworks do it.  Is it considered a good or bad practice by the community? :P

It appears to be more efficient, but it looks a little confusing because I'm used to getThing() and setThing() in PHP. This style reminds me of jQuery.

Comment: and if I want set the var to `false` or `null`?

Comment: You are right, it is very confusing and counter intuitive. I wished that PHP would offer something like properties.

Comment: jQuery is precisely what it mimicks. Obviously many coders get easily confused by dual-purpose accessor methods. But it can aid API usability in some cases, and it's common for fluent interfaces. (Preferrable to shallow getters and setters that ought to be absent.)

Comment: @mario - Fluent interfaces, as i understand them, do always return a value, you can rely on it. The confusing part in the example above is, that the function may or may not return a value, this merely calls for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a **Get** and a **Set** for ***all*** variables in an object.

So instead of the function getName() and getAge()

You can use  get('name') or set('name', 'Foo Bar');

The functions would look like this:

```
    public function __set($name, $value) {
    $method = 'set' . $name;
    if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid Client property');
    }
    $this->$method($value);
}

public function __get($name) {
    $method = 'get' . $name;
    if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid Client property');
    }
    return $this->$method();
}
```

If you're looking for a efficient alternative to getters and setters, this might be it.

Comment: I would go for this way of implementing getters and settings, big advantage is that by doing this you force the object to only have the properties you want it to have. If someone actually makes a typo and assigns a value of some property that should not exist your code will tell you about your error! Helps you catch your typo's!!!

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Indeed it would, though getting direct feedback on what you are doing is usually preferable.

Comment: @bkwint, so enable `display_errors` in development. While magic methods are indeed useful, using them to identify typos is the silliest thing I've heard today.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, it's a nice side effect, nothing more.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it a good idea to replace getter and/or setter methods with a single method handling both?

**No.**

Maybe for a very specific use case. But no. Consider in your own code if you need to assign `null` to `$name`. Your code would not allow that.

As far as *efficient* as in *performance*, I don't see how. In the end, you still make one method call. Either to *set* or *get*.

If you mean *efficient* as in less code, to your own point, you've sacrificed readability. Which is more inefficient. Especially over time.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, having a function that one time return something and another time set something else and return void, is never a good idea (readability and findbug reasons)

Answer (score 2):

I have also used the single method jQuery-like solution and did like it but had read some posts that for some reason made me think others thought it was bad practice. But now I am reading around again and came across this post.

My solutions had (disclaimer: condensed formatting)

```
class Person {
    protected $name;
    protected $age;
    public function name($value = null) {
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->name = (string) $value;
            return $this;
        }
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function age($value = null) {
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->age = (int) $value;
            return $this;
        }
        return $this->age;
    }
}
```

I did enjoy this type of interface for a class

```
$person1 = new Person();
$person1->name('Bob')->age(30);
echo $person->name();
```

The general idea was that if $value was null then send back the property, otherwise set the property to $value, maybe type casting it or running it through some other filters then returning the instance of the class.

Now that I am re-visiting this, Im not really sure why this is so bad *EXCEPT* for the fact that you may confuse your IDE with return values since it will either be your property data type OR your class.

Needing to set the value to false still works here, in the (for me) edge-case where I need to set to null then I would just one-off/case-by-case change the default/condition check to accomodate.

I did appreciate the lesser boilerplate feeling of not having to write two methods AND their associated phpdoc blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I generally like to give programmers that are using my code the choice between direct accessing protected variables through __set() and __get() and by a my custom getter/setter.  I have found that using func_num_args() in my getter/setter to be an acceptable solution.  It is slightly slower than just testing for null but allows me to set the value to null.

```
/**
 * Getter/Setter for Class::$someVar.
 * 
 * @access public 
 * @param mixed Value for Class::$someVar to be set to.
 * @return mixed If no parameter are passed it returns the current value for Class::$var.
 */
public function someVar($value = null) {
    if (func_num_args() > 0) {
        $this->someVar = $value;
        return $this;
    } else {
        return $this->someVar;
    }
}
```

Every choice we make in programming is a compromise. The trick is to figure out where you CAN compromise and where you Shouldn't.